putting a list of words to the predefined categories
I have a list of around 1000 words of different food items. I have 36 categories which I want to put that list in these categories according to their meaning. how can I do that?
I am not sure if it is easier to do it manually or using ML
I tried clustering

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
